# How to determine device location using CoreMotion framework?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

For instance: app is runs and we initialized the start coordinates (`x=0, y=0, z=0`) and coordinate system is equal to device coordinate system at startup and then it must be fixed i.e. not attached to device. I want to determine `x, y, z` in each moment when event of `MotionManager` fired like this:

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { data, error in
    x = ...
    y = ...
    z = ...
}
```

But i don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
motionManger.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (deviceMotion, deviceMotionError) in
            self.handleDeviceMotionUpdates(deviceMotion!)
}

func handleDeviceMotionUpdates(_ deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion){

   let acceleration = deviceMotion.gravity
   print("Acceleration X>\(acceleration.x) Y>\(acceleration.y) Z>\(acceleration.z)\n")

   let userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration
   print("User Acceleration X>\(userAcceleration.x) Y>\(userAcceleration.y) Z>\(userAcceleration.z)\n")
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want exact formulas to determine x,y,z not just printing them out.

Comment: Just use `acceleration.x`, `acceleration.y`, `acceleration.z` where you want to use. It will give you x, y, z value.

Comment: Sorry but you don't answered to my question directly.

Comment: No problem. Cheers.